# Top 10 unless count is zero

Tags: sql, count

This is probably easy, but eludes me. 
SQL server2005
I want to show top 100 but if there are not 100 only want to show those and not include zero counts in the result

```
SELECT    TOP (100) UserName, FullName_Company, FullName,
                      (SELECT  COUNT(*)
                        FROM          dbo.Member_Ref
                        WHERE      (RefFrom_UserName = dbo.view_Members.UserName) AND (RefDate >= '5/1/2010') AND (RefDate <= '6/1/2010')) 
                  AS RefFromCount           
FROM         dbo.view_Members
WHERE (MemberStatus = N'Active')
ORDER BY RefFromCount DESC
```

I have tried using Group By and HAVING COUNT(*)>0 all with the same wrong results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I join to a subquery with quantities and in the where part I filter by quantity > 0.

```
SELECT TOP (100) UserName, FullName_Company, FullName, Quantity AS RefFromCount          
FROM         dbo.view_Members
JOIN (
    SELECT RefFrom_UserName, COUNT(*) as Quantity
    FROM          dbo.Member_Ref
    WHERE      (RefDate >= '5/1/2010') AND (RefDate <= '6/1/2010')
    GROUP BY RefFrom_UserName
) as Q on Q.RefFrom_UserName = dbo.view_Members.UserName
WHERE (MemberStatus = N'Active')
AND Quantity > 0
ORDER BY RefFromCount DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
SELECT TOP (100) UserName, FullName_Company, FullName,
                      (SELECT  COUNT(*)
                        FROM          dbo.Member_Ref
                        WHERE      (RefFrom_UserName = dbo.view_Members.UserName) 
                          AND (RefDate >= '5/1/2010') AND (RefDate <= '6/1/2010')) 
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
                  AS RefFromCount           
FROM         dbo.view_Members
WHERE (MemberStatus = N'Active')
ORDER BY RefFromCount DESC
```

The added `HAVING` clause on the inner query will inherently cut out results with 0 counts.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it still returns 100 items but the RefFromCount is NULL for the balance of the list that previously displayed as 0. I want to show 100 items if there are 100, or only 90 if that is all there were.

Comment: HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 there wouldn't return NULL and it will show and user with zero count?

Comment: i expect that too,  but that is the result i get

Answer (score 0):

Does SQL Server 2005 have keyword like "limit" in MySQL? (If so, there is a very simple solution for this kind of task)